# update!: Tkinter python 2.7 problems

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.topFrame = Tkinter.Frame()
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.wm_title("My first window!")
        self.label = Label(self.root, text="Enter your weight")
        self.label.pack(padx=20,pady=10)
        self.labeltext = StringVar()
        self.labeltext.set("Enter your height!")
        Label(self.root, textvariable=self.labeltext).pack()
        self.entrytext2 = StringVar()
        Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.entrytext2).pack()
        self.entrytext2.trace('w', self.entry_changed)
        self.buttontext = StringVar()
        self.buttontext.set("Bouton")
        Button(self.root, textvariable=self.buttontext, command=self.clicked1).pack()
        self.entrytext = StringVar()
        Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.entrytext).pack()
        self.entrytext.trace('w', self.entry_changed)

    def calcBMI(self):
        weight = float(self.entrytext2.get())
        inches = float(self.entrytext.get())
        BMI = (weight * 703)/ inches **2
        if BMI > 18.5 and BMI < 25:
                self.labeltext.set(BMI)
        elif BMI < 18.5:
                print ' Your BMI is Underweight ', self.value.set(BMI)
        else:
                print ' Your BMI is Overweight ', self.value.set(BMI)




    def clicked1(self):
        response = tkMessageBox.askyesno("Confirm", "You clicked?")
        if response:
            self.labeltext.set("You've been clicked!")
            self.buttontext.set("Butttttttton")
            print response

MyApp()
```

So when I edited it I get:

```
File "window1.py", line 45, in <module>
    MyApp()
  File "window1.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.root = Tk()
NameError: global name 'Tk' is not defined
```

Comment: You mixed up two pieces of good advice. Try `Tkinter.Tk()` in the offending line.

Comment: And it would have been best if you had appended to your question instead of replacing it all. Now it appears as if Gandaro and jab9bansai gave incorrect answers, while they were in fact very helpful.

Comment: @user173314 Follow Junuxx's advice. Tk() is a class within the module Tkinter, when you simply import Tkinter, python needs to know where the magic term Tk() comes from, in this case it comes from the module you imported. If you read the URL that Gandaro provides, it will help you understand this greatly.

Answer (score 4):

Try just calling Frame(), instead of Tkinter.Frame(). You have used a wild import which is this line of code...

```
from Tkinter import *
```

The namespace "Tkinter" is thus already defined through that statement and each invididual method and class frome that namespace is now available for use directly.

Tkinter.Frame() would work in the case of using

```
import Tkinter
```

Instead of the former. I haven't tested your code for further problems if they exist.

Answer (score 1):

Since you imported "* from" Tkinter, you cannot use its name to refer to it.  To use  the name `Tkinter` in your program you have to import it like that:

```
import Tkinter
```

Or you just remove the "`Tkinter.`" from your code and leave the import statement like so.

Please read http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html